Sum of a Normal and a Chi2 distribution
I am doing some Monte Carlo exercises, and I have to derive the distribution of the following equation:
$y= x + x \times u$
where $u\sim T_k$ is a Student $t$ with $k$ d.f. and $x\sim \sqrt{\frac{\chi^2_{k}}{k}}$. I know that $x \times u \sim N(0,1)$, but I do not know the distribution of $y$. Is there a known distribution for the distribution of $y$ or some theorem that allows me to approximate it?
Thank you in advance!!

Is $T_k$ a Student $t$ distribution with $k$ degrees of freedom?

You should be able to calculate the mean and variance: for example the mean is $\sqrt{\frac{2}{k}} \frac{\Gamma((k+1)/2)}{\Gamma(k/2)}$. The distribution of $y$ seems to be slightly right skewed.

Yes, sorry, $_$ is a Student $$ with $k$ degrees of freedom. Does the variance have an analytical formula in this case?
